# navbar-header would change the total height of the menu

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I customized the bootstrap.css to make the nav navbar-default to 30px.
Now, in navbar-header which is within nav navbar-default, when I add an image with height 50px, the entire nav navbar-default becomes 50px.

Previously:
[image]

Now:
[image]

Comment: You have to provide some code - best the code you changed/added.

Comment: That is not an actual problem. The container of the image resizes to the size required by the element. If this container is nested inside another, it would obviously increase the parent container size as well. After adding the image, you might want to set a vertical-alignment for all other elements, so they get on line with the image.

Comment: Please provide the code , with the exact detail of what you want